# Devise Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working with Rails4 and using devise,

I have generate classes like this,

```
Class User
end

Class Doctor < User
end

Class Patient < User
end
```

While registering User i am asking user he/she is doctor or patient using drop down list in user sign_up page. After storing it will store as _type: "Doctor" or "Patient". Thats Perfect!!!

I need to achieve sign_up for doctor where he should act as Doctor as well as Patient...!!!!!!! That to using same email address!!!

If doctor sign_up using d@d.com then he can sign_up for patient using same(d@d.com) email.

Please Help me in this regard...

Comment: don't use STI because this store all values in single table and this technique create multiple null. instead of that use polymorphic association

Comment: you can take two more field in user table like is_doctor and is_patient if both of them are true then after login you should ask user which role he want to use at that time

Comment: you do not need the account_id and account_type field than.

Comment: @HarsHarI I already using STI, I can't move it up... Any other solution!!!

Comment: @NitinJ, yes i will try for that.. Can you please give more information!!!

Comment: check ihc.cmisol.org if you sign up as both role after login it will ask which role you want to perform and after that a button always appearsto switch role on the top of page. if you like that i will tell you the way i do that

Comment: @NitinJ Nice post, can i remove the validatable from devise for email!!! How you achieve for unique email id for two models in STI.

Answer (score 0):

This smells like the "rolify" gem, assigning multiple roles to a single user...

https://github.com/EppO/rolify

I have used this in combination with CanCan, to allow users to access certain pages/models, based on their role(s)